# Compare (not sync) the contents of a local folder and a AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, pgp

I need to compare the contents of a local folder with a AWS S3 bucket so that where there are differences a script is executed on the local files.
The idea is that local files (pictures) get encrypted and uploaded to S3. Once the upload has occurred I delete the encrypted copy of the pictures to save space. The next day new files get added to the local folder. I need to check between the local folder and the S3 bucket which pictures have already been encrypted and uploaded so that I only encrypt the newly added pictures rather than all of them all over again. I have a script that does exactly this between two local folders but I'm struggling to adapt it so that the comparison is performed between a local folder and a S3 bucket.
Thank you to anyone who can help.

Here is the actual script I am currently using for my picture sorting, encryption and back up to S3:

## !/bin/bash

perl /volume1/Synology/scripts/Exiftool/exiftool '-createdate

perl /volume1/Synology/scripts/Exiftool/exiftool '-model=camera model missing' -r -if '(not $model)' -overwrite_original -r /volume1/photo/"input"/ --ext .DS_Store -i "@eaDir"

perl /volume1/Synology/scripts/Exiftool/exiftool '-Directory

cd /volume1/Synology/Pictures/"Pictures Glacier back up"/"Compressed encrypted pics for Glacier"/post_2016/ && (cd /volume1/Synology/Pictures/Pictures/post_2016/; find . -type d ! -name .) | xargs -i mkdir -p "{}"

while IFS= read -r file; do /usr/bin/gpg --encrypt -r xxx@yyy.com /volume1/Synology/Pictures/Pictures/post_2016/**/*/*/$(basename "$file" .gpg); done < <(comm -23 <(find /volume1/Synology/Pictures/Pictures/post_2016 -type f -printf '%f.gpg\n'|sort) <(find /volume1/Synology/Pictures/"Pictures Glacier back up"/"Compressed encrypted pics for Glacier"/post_2016 -type f -printf '%f\n'|sort))

rsync -zarv --exclude=@eaDir --include="*/" --include="*.gpg" --exclude="*" /volume1/Synology/Pictures/Pictures/post_2016/ /volume1/Synology/Pictures/"Pictures Glacier back up"/"Compressed encrypted pics for Glacier"/post_2016/ 
find /volume1/Synology/Pictures/Pictures/post_2016/ -name "*.gpg" -type f -delete

/usr/bin/aws s3 sync /volume1/Synology/Pictures/"Pictures Glacier back up"/"Compressed encrypted pics for Glacier"/post_2016/ s3://xyz/Pictures/post_2016/ --exclude "*" --include "*.gpg" --sse

Answer (score 0):

It would be inefficient to continually compare the local and remote folders, especially as the quantity of objects increases.

A better flow would be:

- Unencrypted files are added to a local folder
- Each file is:

  - Copied to another folder in an encrypted state
  - Once that action is confirmed, the original file is then deleted
- Files in the encrypted local folder are copied to S3

  - Once that action is confirmed, the source file is then deleted

The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) has an [`aws s3 sync`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) command that makes it easy to copy new/modified files to an Amazon S3 bucket, but this could be slow if you have thousands of files.